The hypercompleteness swindle
In this paper by Devalapurkar and Heine, there is a remarkable "swindle" at Lemma 4.17. We first establish an equivalence using Whitehead theorem, and then show that localization preserves the truth of the statement. Then since every presheaf topos is hypercomplete, we get the result for any topos, even non-hypercomplete ones.
This is of course very cool, but it is now not so clear how one may formalize this synthetically. My current approach is to circumvent this lemma and try to arrive at the main results from another route. But one is still curious: what axioms are needed to synthetically perform this swindle?
It seems that we can perform a similar argument using presheaves valued in $\infty$-truncated types. But this would break the universe levels horrendously, as without any presentability hypotheses, $\infty$-truncation raises the level. Not to mention the fact that taking presheaves is already hard to manage size-wise. Is it possible with only propositional resizing? Or do we need something even stronger like adjoint functor theorems?
